# Linear transformations... $T(\mathbf v)\ne0$, $T^2 - 0$... Prove $\mathbf v$ and $T(\mathbf v)$ are linearlly independent...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

> Suppose $T:\mathbb R^n \to\mathbb R^n$ is a linear transformation and suppose that $\mathbf v$ is a vector such that $T(\mathbf v) \ne 0$ but $T^2(\mathbf v) = 0$ (where $T^2 = T \circ T$) Prove that $\mathbf v$ and $T(\mathbf v)$ are linearlly independent.

I have no idea where to start with this! Any insight?

Comment: What if $v$ and $T(v)$ are linearly dependent?  Write down what that means.  Now what can you say about $T^2(v)$?

Answer (score 2):

We must show that if $c_1 v + c_2 T(v) = 0$, then $c_1=c_2=0$.

Now apply $T$ to both sides of $c_1 v + c_2 T(v) = 0$ to obtain

$c_1T(v) + c_2 T^2(v) = T(0) = 0$.  But $T^2(v) = 0$, so we get

$c_1T(v) = 0 \implies  c_1 = 0$ since $T(v) \neq 0$.  So $c_2T(v) = 0$, but $T(v) \neq 0 \implies c_2=0$ as well.